# Android screen orientation sensor portrait in Galaxy nexus

Tags: android, screen-orientation, galaxy

I am developing an android app where i need to set dual side landscape orientation for tablets and dual side portrait mode for phones.

I have tested it on many phones and tablets, and everything works fine, excepts on my Galaxy nexus phone(version 4.2.2).Some how the the dual side portrait does seem to works only on this phone.

I am using the below code to achieve it,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if ((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
    {   

        //phone
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //dual side portrait mode
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8)
        {
            this.setRequestedOrientation(7);

        }


    }
    else if ((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
    {
        //tablet
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //dual side landscape mode
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8)
        {
            this.setRequestedOrientation(6);
        }
    }


    else if ((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)
    {
        //tablet
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //dual side landscape mode
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8)
        {
            this.setRequestedOrientation(6);

        }
    }


}
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: "Some how the the dual side portrait does seem to works only on this phone" - can you clarify - `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT` is *not* working on Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: yep, instead of specifying SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT, i am using its constant value 7 to setrequestedorientation.

Comment: That is weird. I can confirm it doesn't work on my Galaxy Nexus either...will see if I can find anything.

Comment: Thanks..But,any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Nope, seems like a bug to me. Even if I set it to fullSensor, or don't set anything, I can't get reversePortrait. All other 3 orientations work for me. Haven't been able to find anything online about it.

Comment: Plase do let me know if you find anything. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem in "GT-I8200L" device.